# Tengo un problema con if, else python

Tags: python

```
# Viajes
TI=raw_input("Tipo de autobus: ");
KM=raw_input("Kilometros a recorrer: ");
NPR=raw_input("Numero de personas: ");
if TI:"A"
CK=2000
else:
CK=3000
if NPR<20
NP=20
else
NP=NPR
TO=NP*CK*KM
CP=TO/NPR
print("La persona pagara: "), CP
print("El costo del viaje es: "), TO
```

Al hacer este ejercicio cuando ingreso `if TI=A`, `if TI==A`, me da Syntax error. La única manera de poder ponerlo fue `if TI:"A"` cosa que no entiendo realmente.

Luego al ingresar `else` me da otro error de syntax de igual forma

No sé realmente que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: qué tipo de dato es "A"?

Comment: Son 2 tipos de autobuses A y B (String), pero claramente cuando lo introduje sin las comillas no resulto en nada. Y al introducir las comillas ya no mandaba error

Comment: entonces ya resolviste tu problema?

Comment: No :(, a pesar de que ya no muestra ese error al ingresar "else" me da otro error en esa linea

Comment: podría ayudarte pero tu código se ve mal. Para pegar código en este sitio, debes indentar con 4 espacios cada línea. O bien, marca todo el código y has click en la herramienta que muestra dos llaves { } Puedes editar tu pregunta en todo momento.

Comment: Vaya, gracias soy nuevo en este sitio.

Comment: Aquí hay gente espectacular. Solo debes redactar bien las preguntas y darlas a entender de la mejor manera.

Comment: Indéntalo tal cual como lo tienes en tu editor.

Comment: Trate de identar, pero al hacerlo sale "unexpected indent"

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta. Bienvenido al sitio y que te vaya bien en tus estudios de programación.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos errores básico en tu código:

- `raw_input` retorna siempre una cadena por lo que debes pasr la cadena e tipo entero para poder operar con los datos.
- Tienes errores de sintaxis ya que después de los condicionales (`if`, `else`, `elif`) debes usar `:` para separar el bloque de código a ejecutar de la condición en si.

El código deberia ser algo así:

```
TI = raw_input("Tipo de autobus: ")
KM = int(raw_input("Kilometros a recorrer: "))
NPR = int(raw_input("Numero de personas: "))

if TI == "A":
    CK = 2000
else:
    CK = 3000

if NPR<20:
    NP = 20
else:
    NP = NPR

TO = NP * CK * KM
CP = TO / NPR

print "La persona pagara: ", CP
print "El costo del viaje es: ", TO
```

En cuanto a lo del tipo del autobús. `TI` es una cadena introducida por el usuario. Como cadena debe ser comparada con otra cadena, por eso debes usar las comillas. Si haces `if TI:"A"` solo esta comprobando que TI no es una cadena vacía, no si vale "A", debe ser `if TI == "A"`. Si `A` y `B` hacen referencia a variables que almacenen cadenas entonces irán sin comillas, pero igualmente usan el operador de comparación `==`:

```
A = "A" 
B = "B"

TI = raw_input("Tipo de autobus: ")
KM = int(raw_input("Kilometros a recorrer: "))
NPR = int(raw_input("Numero de personas: "))

if TI == A:
    CK = 2000
else:
    CK = 3000

if NPR<20:
    NP = 20
else:
    NP = NPR

TO = NP * CK * KM
CP = TO / NPR

print "La persona pagara: ", CP
print "El costo del viaje es: ", TO
```

Recuerda que en Python la identación es crucial ya que, a diferencia de otro lenguajes que marcan con llaves o palabras clave específicas los bloques de código, Python lo hace con la identación. Para no complicarte la vida intenta seguir estas pautas:

- Usa siempre espacios para identar, PEP 8 recomienda usar cuatro espacios entre cada nivel de identación.
- No es recomendable usar tabulaciones para identar, son poco portables (una tabulación no es lo mismo en todos los equipos o editores) y dan dolores de cabeza cuando quedan ocultas.
- **Nunca mezcles espacios y tabulaciones**. Los editores e IDEs para Python suelen ya venir configurados para identar con cuatro espacios (aunque use la tecla Tab para identar) pero estate atento si usas código copiado de la web, aún quedan códigos identados usando tabulaciones.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla, realmente no me di cuenta del int al principio, en cuanto a las otras cosas realmente no las sabia, y tu comentario me ha servido de mucha ayuda pues con lo poco que me han enseñado en clase no habian comentado hasta ahora esas cosas. Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!.

Comment: @JoseMartinez recuerda marcar aquella respuesta que te sea más útil como [aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) para que otros usuarios con el mismo porblema sepan de su utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores de indentación, en algunos if y else te faltan los : y para recibir números desde un input, debes utilizar solo input, y no raw_input.

Aqui está tu código funcionando, por lo menos con lo que tienes hasta ahora:

```
# Viajes
TI=raw_input("Tipo de autobus: ");
KM=input("Kilometros a recorrer: ");
NPR=input("Numero de personas: ");
if TI=="A":
    CK=2000
else:
    CK=3000
if NPR<20:
    NP=20
else:
    NP=NPR

TO=NP*CK*KM
CP=TO/NPR
print("La persona pagara: "), CP
print("El costo del viaje es: "), TO
```

Espero haberte ayudado y buen viaje en el mundo de la programación.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, aun estoy empezando en este mundo y claramente tengo errores, pero se que ya puedo mejorar con esto, muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!.

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, buena suerte.